Using Informix in Python
I'm trying to develop an API in Python using Informix, but I can only install IfxPy (the driver I found to use with Informix) on Linux, but I would need to install it or another driver on Windows.
Does anyone know how to install a driver that I can connect to Informix on Windows?
Thanks.
I tried to compile the Ifxpy in windows.
